# How to validate if its a login page using webdriverio

Tags: javascript, selenium, callback, webdriver-io

I am using Javascript, webdriverio (v2.1.2) to perform some data extraction from an internal site. The internal site is SSO enabled, so if I have been authenticated on another application, I need not login for this application (common in enterprise intranet applications). 
I plan to achieve the below,

- Create a client with required capabilities
- Pass the required URL
- For fun : Print the title of the page
- Check if an element exist on the page. If yes, then it's a login page. If not, then it's not login page

  ```
  login = function (username, password) {
  if (!browserClientUtil) {
      throw "Unable to load browserClientUtil.js";
  }
  browserClientUtil
    .createClient()
    .url(_Url)
    .title(function (err, res) {
          console.log('Title is: ' + res.value);
    }) .isExisting('input#login_button.login_button', function (err, isExisting) {
      browserClientUtil.getCurrentClient()
          .setValue('input#USER.input', username)
        .setValue('input#PASSWORD.input', password)
        //.saveScreenshot('ultimatixLoginDetails.png')
        .click('input#login_button.login_button')
        .pause(100);
        handlePostLogin();
  });
  ```

  };

Is this the best way to do? I tried to separate the code for verifying login page in a separate function, it didn't work as everything in webdriver happens as part of callback and I am not sure if I am doing it in a right way. 
**How do I return from a callback, that will in-turn be the final value returned by that function?**

```
    login = function (username, password) {
    if (!browserClientUtil) {
        throw "Unable to load browserClientUtil.js";
    }
    browserClientUtil
      .createClient()
      .url(_Url)
      .title(function (err, res) {
            console.log('Title is: ' + res.value);
      });
      if(isThisLoginPage()){
            browserClientUtil.getCurrentClient()
            .setValue('input#USER.input', username)
          .setValue('input#PASSWORD.input', password)
          //.saveScreenshot('ultimatixLoginDetails.png')
          .click('input#login_button.login_button')
          .pause(100);
          handlePostLogin();
        }
};

    isThisLoginPage = function() {
    var client = browserClientUtil.getCurrentClient();
    if(!client) {
        throw "Unable to get reference for current client, hence cannot validate if this is login page.";
    }

    client.isExisting('input#login_button.login_button', function (err, isExisting) {
        if(isExisting) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I know that, if an inner function call is asynchronous, then all the functions 'wrapping' this call must also be asynchronous in order to 'return' a response. So, my final question would be - was my first method the best way or may be I should look into deferred and promises to make the code modular and readable? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own workflow by creating own commands that wrap other ones. For example you can make an own command to login:

```
browserClientUtil.addCommand("login", function(url, user, pw, cb) {
    this.url(url)
        .setValue('#username', user)
        .setValue('#password', pw)
        .submitForm('#loginForm')
        .call(cb);
});
```

This allows you to hide "complex" asynchronous webdriver actions behind a simple function. It is easy to create an powerful toolchain. At the end your test script looks like:

```
browserClientUtil
    .login("http://example.com/login", "john.doe", "testpass")
    .getTitle(function(err, title) {
        console.log(title);
    })
    // ...
```

Cheers